# Save data from selected picker view row

Tags: ios, swift

I have a a picker view in my view controller and want to save the data from the selected row in a variable. I don't want to have a button. My Picker View is attached to the view controllers delegate and datasource. Here is my picker view code:

```
    var colors = ["ISERV 1","ISERV 2","ISERV 3"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return colors[row]
    }
```

Comment: Here is the example of picker view in objective - c just convert it to Swift
http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement didSelectRow:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    let variable = colors[row]
}
```

Comment: Does it update its value automatically when the user rotates the picker?

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot!

Comment: But when i return the value of the "variable" because I want to use the String then is the value of "variable" "". Please help me!

Comment: Could you be clearer with your question? You could store "variable" globally, or update a UI element like a UILabel

Comment: I changed the constant from the upper code to a redeclaration  of a variable with a value of type String. The value is "ISERV 1" so when the user doesn't rotate the picker then is the "selected " value of the variable (the first row). But when the user rotate the value of the variable won't changes its value to the selected row so value stays at "ISERV 1" . I already tried to return the value of variable. Should I send you my code?

Comment: How can I redeclare the function

Answer (score 0):

This code you can be try

```
var numbers = [1, 2 , 3]


var num:Int! = 1


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int 
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component:       Int) -> Int 
{
    return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return numbers[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{

     num = numbers[row]
    
 }

@IBAction func saveAccounts(_ sender: UIButton)
{


    
    if num == 1 {
        
        let aleart = UIAlertController(title: "The number is ONE", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { (action) in
                   }
                   aleart.addAction(action)
                   present(aleart, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }else if num == 2 {
        
        let aleart = UIAlertController(title:"The number is TOW", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { (action) in
                   }
                   aleart.addAction(action)
                   present(aleart, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else if num == 3 {
        let aleart = UIAlertController(title: "The number is THREE", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { (action) in
                   }
                   aleart.addAction(action)
                   present(aleart, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```